# Handle touch gestures in two views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two `UIScrollViews` one over another in the hierarchy. I name it: `scrollView1` which is the `view` from the front and `scrollView2` which is the `view` from behind.

The `scrollView1` has a `transparent` `view` in `CGRect(0,0,320,568)` and some `content` in `CGRect(0,568,320,300)`. If the user scroll the screen vertically he needs to see the view that stars from `y = 568`.

The `scrollView2` contains some `UIImages` displayed horizontally, each `image` starts at `origin.x = screenWidth * imageIndex`, where `imageIndex` starts from `0`. So the `scrollView2` have to `scroll` horizontally through `images`, also it has some `UIButtons` in the `content`.

How can I do to be able to `scroll` the `scrollView1` vertically but in the same time be able to `scroll` `scrollView2` horizontally and also trigger `UIButtonEventTouchUpInside` on its buttons. The method `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` doesn't help me because I have to choose if current `view` handle or not the event.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have a single scrollview that can scroll in both directions?

Comment: I think it needs too many adjustments as time as the content from scrollView2 have to remain still while scrolling vertically. Also the projects it's already finished and the screen it's actually too much consuming to be refactored in such a way, I was looking for a light weight solution adapted to my current screen. But thanks, it's a method that could solve this.

Comment: "I have to choose if current view handle or not the event." Does `-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` do you what?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have to check on which view Gesture is added.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{            
 // enter code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For:

> How can I do to be able to scroll the scrollView1 vertically but in the same time be able to scroll scrollView2 horizontally

You need to implement UISwipeGestureRecognizer as:

```
  - (void)didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipe{

if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Left"); // Implement Horizontal Scroll
} else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Right"); // Implement Horizontal Scroll
} else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Up"); // Implement Vertical Scroll
} else if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Down"); // Implement Vertical Scroll
}
}
```

For:

> UIButtonEventTouchUpInside

I am not sure what you are trying to implement, but if your views are overlapping ( one-view behind other), than you need to bring target view to front by changing its `YourTargetView.zPosition`

Comment: I don't know if you caught the question. I have 2 scroll views one over another, each scrollView works if it's in the front , but I need to make the view from behind responsive too. Also scrollView contains several button,so I don't need only the swipe gesture to work.